# Foobar2000 music overview

Tags: foobar2000

I just installed foobar2000 on a new computer and encountered something that I once fixed, but now have forgotten.

[image]

This is from the list overview. Now, all albums are mentioned. What I am used to is a list of the artists, which you can open to view their albums. Not like this where the albums are already shown.

Can someone please tell me where I can find the setting for this(and how to achieve the format I want?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which foobar version are you using?

I'm using 0.9.6.7 in Wine in an openSUSE machine. I can just set this behavior by the interface itself like in this image:

[image: Foobar view artist]

You can change your interface to show this option in in File->Preferences->Display->Default User Interface->Theme Management->QuickSetup.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I simply forgot that option even existed...

Answer (score 1):

Or best you can create your own order with [title formatting](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Titleformat_Reference) in the "album list" (or "album list panel" if you use columns ui)

file > preferences > media library > album list (panel)

for example here is mine for alphabetic order / artists / album / cd / tracks list:

```
$if(%various%,~Various Artists|$if(%album%,'['$replace($left(%album%,1),1,#,2,#,3,#,4,#,5,#,6,#,7,#,8,#,9,#,0,#)']'|%album%$if($meta(album artist), - $meta(album artist)),~No Album[|%genre%])|[CD%DISCNUMBER%|][%tracknumber%. ]%artist% - %title%,$if(%album artist%,'['$replace($left(%album artist%,1),1,#,2,#,3,#,4,#,5,#,6,#,7,#,8,#,9,#,0,#)']'|%album artist%|,~No '('Album')' Artist|)$if(%album%,'['[%date%]']' %album%|,~No Album|['['%date%']' ])[CD%DISCNUMBER%|][%tracknumber%. ]$ifgreater($meta_num(artist),1,[%artist% - ],[%track artist% - ])%title%)
```

but it's dependent of how you tag your mp3, and it could be less complex like the default one, "by artist"

```
%<artist>%|%album%|[[%discnumber%.]%tracknumber%. ][%track artist% - ]%title%
```